# Uploaded avatars are displayed in very low quality in combined flair

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, combined-flair

Uploaded avatars are displayed in a very low quality in the combined flair.

[image] 
[image]
[image]

---

They are displayed fine in the per-site flairs.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This bug only affects uploaded avatars. Gravatars still work fine.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: (For future reference, when this has been fixed: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yWIrg.png).)

Comment: Maybe related: some per-site themes [show no image at all](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jDebJ.png) for me. (I uploaded a slightly altered *copy* of my Gravatar flair some time ago; never used flair though.)

Comment: @Arjan - What you posted is for site specific flair. Did you post a bug for that? If not, please do.

Comment: Meanwhile, @Oded, all is fine [for my site specific flair](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/84237/arjan/flair). No idea when it changed (like I wrote I don't use it). (Didn't know you're working at SE! Forget the flair: the [team page](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) is outdated!)

Comment: Take a look now: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134300/jeremy-banks/flair

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The network flair is on another code path from the per-site flair, causing this issue.

A fix is in the next build, though the network flair is cached, so you will probably only see it change within 24 hours.

---

[image] 
[image] 
[image]

Comment: I just noticed that moderator's mark ♦ behind your name. Am I late to notice it?

Comment: @hims056: He's a dev now. See his profile.

Comment: @hims056 - It's been there since Thursday, I believe. And it _is_ subtle ;)